# How can I provide proof to a Visa Officer that I transferred funds from one account of mine to another?

Tags: visas, study, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have two accounts in my name in two different banks. My primary bank was not cooperating with me to send money overseas to a school for my master's degree. Instead of arguing with them, I transferred the funds to my secondary account and wired the funds from there.

To transfer the funds from my primary account to my secondary account, I wrote a cheque. The bank statement clearly shows the transaction occurring on the same date for the amount I wrote but the secondary bank has a remark in the statement saying "From Acc. No. - XXX" where XXX is presumably the sender's (i.e. my other account number) - except the number listed does not match my primary account number (from where I transferred the funds).

In order to obtain a student visa, I must submit my bank statements. My worry is that the Visa Officer will note that the account numbers don't match and ban me for misrepresentation.

How can I prove to the visa officer that I really did transfer the funds between my two accounts?

Comment: How did you pay in the cheque? Do you have a receipted credit slip? You can ask the bank on which the cheque was drawn to give you a photocopy of it.

Comment: Submit both statement along with photo copy of transfer cheque and original deposit slip from secondary account .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple. Show it to them that at the time that money was added to one statement, it was deducted from the other statement.

Accounts should have matched, banking doesn’t work like *something doesn’t match up*. But let’s say for any reason they just don’t, when you show an equal drop of balance from your other account I don’t think it will be taken as misrepresentation still.